# Not able to use the same model from previous page

Tags: ember.js

In my first page, I am getting the model like :

```
model:function(){
        return this.get('store').findAll('offer').then(function(data){
            return data.get('firstObject');
        });
    },
```

when user click on next button, I am taking them in to next page. where i require the updated model from previous page. so I am trying to use the same model as what i updated like:

```
model:function(){
        var model = this.modelFor('HK.cs2i.cs2i.purchase.purchaseDetails');
        console.log('model is', model);
        return model;
    },
```

But on the console, I am getting the mode as `undefied`. is it require to do any workarounds or something else to access the previous mode?

any one help me here?

Comment: In application it works. But I use `addon` so not works

Answer (score 0):

modelFor will work only if it's in the same parent-child route hierarchy.

In your case, previousPage and nextPage should have parent-child relationship route hierarchy. if you want to share data to different route you can go for storing the data in service.

https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Route/methods/modelFor?anchor=modelFor

Comment: Even can't I use peekAll?

Comment: peekAll - you can use it from everywhere,